# Как обеспечить взаимодействие между разными View в MVVM?

Tags: java, mvvm

Пишу программу с довольно сложным интерфейсом на Swing. Пытаюсь применить для этого паттерн MVVM. Мне говорили что глупо применить его в Swing, типа есть WPF, вот там и применяй, но я всё же решил попробовать. Получается примерно так: в каждом ActionListener я вызываю метод backbind(), потом какой то метод у ViewModel, потом bind(). Проблема появляется когда действие в одном View должно влиять на другие View.

Можно сделать ViewModel с общими данными синглтоном. И в том слушателе, который влияет на несколько View делать backbind() в эту глобальную ViewModel. И вызывать ее метод. 
Backbind это передача данных от View к ViewModel

Но как сделать так что бы несколько View сделали bind?
То есть забрали данные у ViewModel, после того как она с ними что то сделала.

ActionListener который вызвал это действие влияющее на несколько View находится в одном View. И из него я никак не могу вызвать методы bind() других View